# can not add object String fields from one ArrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I can not see error in my code. Code is very simple. I must add objects field(String) from ArrayList/Product/    to ArrayList/String/ . Here is my code:

```
 public class Controller extends JFrame{

public Controller(){

   ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<TestPanels.manu.size();i++){

        list.add(TestPanels.manu.get(i).getName());
         }
```

If I try `list.add("some String")  IT IS WORKING`  , but `list.add(TestPanels.manu.get(i).getName());`  doesnt add ANYTHING.

Can you see what is wrong?

`TestPanels.manu` is OK

```
 static ArrayList<Product> manu = new ArrayList<Product>();

Product nam=new Product("kafa", 90);
Product k = new Product("kafa sa mlekom", 100 );
Product ks = new Product("kafa sa slagom", 120 );
Product kap = new Product("kapucino", 120 );
Product kisela = new Product("kisela voda", 80 );


   .................  some code........

    manu.add(nam);   
manu.add(ks);
manu.add(kap);
manu.add(kisela);
manu.add(k);
```

public class Product {

```
private String name = "noname";
private Double price=new Double(100);

public Product(){
    };

public Product(String name,double price)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
};

public double getPrice(){
return price;}

public void setPrice(Double p){
    price=p;}

public String getName(){
    return name;}

public void setName(String n){
    name=n;}
```

}

`I DID IT. THANK YOU ALL.`

Comment: are you sure your TestPanels list is populated with Product object ??, show us how you populate TestPanels list.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and see what really happens?

Comment: try print `TestPanels.manu.size()`

Comment: Also once you get this working check out the for each loop
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: are sure that `TestPanels.manu.get(i).getName()` is returning **String**?

Comment: are you shure that TestPanels.manu.get(i).getName() does not return null?

Comment: I don't know anything about debugging.  When I do it, it shows no error

Comment: Are you executing this code before populating the list or after it? I believe you are doing that before populating the list.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT. I made 8 classes, 7 classes depend of each other and they do one application.When I run application, then `TestPanels.manu` filled.  Class `Controller` is independ and has own main method. But when I run application, after that I run class `Controller`, it still shows empty `ArrayList<String> list`. WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `list.add(TestPanels.manu.get(i));` not working?

Then your list is most probably not filled.

Comment: `TestPanels.manu` list is OK

Comment: I tested list TestPanels.manu it is OK